# Access Value of a Same key in a dictionary of outside function

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access the same key of a dictionary that called name and I cant change the value of key because it is on server : here is my code :

```
 func infoUser(complition:@escaping ([String:Any]) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "\(offerUrl)/api/user")! //change the url
                //create the session object
                let session = URLSession.shared
                //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET" //set http method as POST
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue( "bearare \(profileKeychain["token"]!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    guard let data = data else {
                        return
                    }
                    print("data is : \(data)")
                    do {
                        //create json object from data
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                            print("this is json format: \(json)")
                        // handle json ...
                            guard let YourName = json["name"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let YourAddress = json["address"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let YourPhone = json["telephone"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let YourEmail = json["email"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let city = json["city"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                            guard let title = city["title"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let country = json["country"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                            guard let names = country["name"] as? String else { return }
                            let dict = ["name":YourName,"address":YourAddress,"telephone":YourPhone,"email":YourEmail,"city":city,"title":title,"country":country,"name" : names] as [String : Any]
                            
                            complition(dict)
                        }
                     
                    } catch let error {
                        print("error is this : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
}
```

I want to access the value of names in country which its key in name like the name of user
and also this is a completion handler that I use it I called it from viewdidLoad() function :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if profileKeychain["token"] != "" {
        infoUser { dict in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.yourNamelbl.text = dict["name"] as? String
            self.yourPhonelbl.text = dict["telephone"] as? String
            self.yourCitylbl.text = dict["title"] as? String
            self.yourMaillbl.text = dict["email"] as? String
            self.yourAddresslbl.text = dict["address"] as? String
                
            // this line
            self.countryNamelbl.text = dict["name" ] as? String }}}
```

and in simulator the name of country and the name of user is same in labels but I dont want to happen this, what's your idea?

thanks for attention

Comment: The country is dict["country"] not dict["name"] isn't it?

Comment: @matt no it isn't ,because country is contain anther array in Jason that one of members that show the name of the country is dict["name"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the value for `"name"` key.

```
let dict = [
    "name": YourName, // First write happens here
    "address": YourAddress,
    "telephone": YourPhone,
    "email": YourEmail,
    "city": city,
    "title": title,
    "country": country,
    "name" : names // Second write, The problem is here
] as [String: Any]
```

---

#### UPDATE

You already have `name` nested inside `country` dictionary, so you don't need to store it one more time at the top level.

You can remove the second write from above code `"name": names` part and use it like following in your `viewDidLoad()`.

```swift
let country = dict["country"] as? [String: Any]
self.countryNamelbl.text = country?["name"] as? String
```

Comment: thanks brother yes I know the problem is here but I can't change the name of the key("name") because its from server

Comment: @Alikazemi See the **UPDATE**.